# How to integrate an interactive opencv window into pyqt5 widget

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt5

I want to draw a mask within an image using opencv (cv2) in an pyqt5 window. I tried using Qwidget and QFrame, I was not able to link these two packages.

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QLabel,  QMessageBox, 
QTableWidgetItem, QWidget, QApplication, QAction
import cv2

import Draw_ui

class DRWindow(QMainWindow, Draw_ui.Ui_Draw):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

        image = cv2.imread('mypic.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

        cv2.namedWindow('Draw here', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
        cv2.setMouseCallback('Draw here', roi1)

    ????????


    #self.graphicsView()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = DRWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the class in this repo: https://github.com/marcel-goldschen-ohm/PyQtImageViewer Along with: https://github.com/hmeine/qimage2ndarray

Comment: @James Does this mean to convert the CV image to a qimage - this would also conclude to transfer all connections from qt to opencv. So on each change on the image I would have to go convert between opencv and qt and vice versa for the input.  In that case I would better stay using opencv - or is there a way to embed the opencv window and use it natively?

Comment: I'm not sure about embedding an opencv window in Qt. I'd just convert the image from opencv to Qt. Then make any updates to the image on the original opencv image using opencv functions and then resend the edited opencv image to Qt.